# Centroid of a semicircle (y-coordinate): $\frac{1}{l(s)}\int y \space ds$

Tags: differential-geometry, centroid

The y-coordinate of the centroid of a (unit) semicircle (upper half) can be defined by the equation

$$\frac{1}{l(s)}\int y \space ds$$

where $\frac{1}{l(s)}=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{2}{\pi}$, $l(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ being the *curve length* of the unit semicircle (parametrisation $\gamma:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\space \gamma(x)=(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$, upper half).

I think
$\int y \space ds=\int_{-1}^{1} y \space ds = \int_{-1}^{1} y \space ||\gamma'(x)||dx=\int_{-1}^{1} y \space \sqrt{(\gamma_x')^2+(\gamma_y')^2}dx= \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}dx = 2$, but the centroid should be $\frac{4\pi}{3} ≠ 2\frac{2}{\pi}$

Comment: As you write about "curve length" it looks like you are asking about the centroid of a semicircular arc, but both the result and your formulas refer instead to the centroid of a semicircular area. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Centroid of the area of the upper half of a unit circle.

Comment: If you are interested in the area, then $ds=dxdy$ is the area element, not the element of line as you seem to think. I'll expand my answer to encompass the two cases.

Comment: Ok so $ds$ is used to refer to any dimensional integrals, depending on the shape?

Comment: Yes, the meaning of $ds$ depends on the kind of integration you are performing. If you were to compute the position of the centroid for a solid semi-sphere then $ds$ would be a volume element, but if you were interested in half a spherical shell, then $ds$ would be an area element, and so on.

Comment: You can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centroids) various examples that may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

For a semicircular area of unit radius we have
$$
\iint y\,dxdy=\int_{-1}^1 dx\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y\,dy={1\over2}\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2) dx={2\over3}.
$$
To get the $y$-coordinate of the centroid we must divide that by the area of the half-circle, which is just $\pi/2$, so that: $y_C=4/(3\pi)$

If, on the other hand, one is interested in finding the centroid of a semicircular arc of unit radius, then we must integrate over the line, taking into account that for our half-circle we have $ds=dx/y$:
$$
\int y\,ds=\int_{-1}^1 y {dx\over y}=\int_{-1}^1 dx=2.
$$
To get the $y$-coordinate of the centroid we must divide that by the length of the semicircular arc, which is just $\pi$, so that: $y_C=2/\pi$.

Comment: The meaning $\int y \space ds$.